# How can I find and replace text after a specific character on each line in Python?

Tags: python, regex, csv, case-insensitive

I have multiple files with lines as below and need to cycle through and find and replace "TEXT" but only after the "="

*static.TEXT.here=change.TEXT.here*

This is my current code but I'm hitting my head against the wall to specify only after "=" as the "TEXT" needing replacement is not in a consistent position across all files

```
import re
src = open(r"sourcefile.txt").read()
dest = open(r"destinationfile.txt","w")
dest.write( re.sub(currentText,replacementText,src, flags=re.I) )
dest.close()
```

**EDIT**

I have taken a slightly different approach and imported csv and used the '=' as a delimiter to create separate rows but am now having difficulty itegrating my existing re.sub code to find and replace the text, code I am using to relevant row:

```
import csv
with open("sourcefile.txt", 'rb') as csvfile:
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= '=')
for row in csvreader:
    if len(row) >1:
        print row[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each line in the file and do the replace after the `=`. For example:

```
formatted_contents = ''
for line in open(r"sourcefile.txt"):
    line_formatted = line.split('=')[-1].replace('TEXT', '**my_text**')
    formatted_contents += line_formatted
```

This assumes there is a `=` in each line. You may want to add some conditions for what you want to do if that isn't in each and every line.

**Updated**

Let's go through this step by step.

### 1. Create the file called `sourcefile.txt` so that I can test the procedure

```
$ cat sourcefile.txt 
static.TEXT.here=change.TEXT.here
more.static.TEXT.here=change.TEXT.here.more
even.more.static.TEXT.here=change.TEXT.here.even.more
```

### 2. Go through the file and print each line to practice reading a file in python

```
>>> for line in open('sourcefile.txt'):
...     print line
... 
static.TEXT.here=change.TEXT.here

more.static.TEXT.here=change.TEXT.here.more

even.more.static.TEXT.here=change.TEXT.here.even.more
```

### 3. Split the contents of the file on the `=`

```
>>> for line in open('sourcefile.txt'):
...     print line.split('=')
... 
['static.TEXT.here', 'change.TEXT.here\n']
['more.static.TEXT.here', 'change.TEXT.here.more\n']
['even.more.static.TEXT.here', 'change.TEXT.here.even.more\n']
```

### 4. We want to take the second part of the `=` side, so we will slice it to do `index[1]` or `index[-1]`

```
>>> for line in open('sourcefile.txt'):
...     print line.split('=')[-1]
... 
change.TEXT.here

change.TEXT.here.more

change.TEXT.here.even.more
```

### 5. Do the replace from `TEXT` to `**MYTEXT**`

```
>>> for line in open('sourcefile.txt'):
...     print line.split('=')[-1].replace('TEXT','**MYTEXT**')
... 
change.**MYTEXT**.here

change.**MYTEXT**.here.more

change.**MYTEXT**.here.even.more
```

### 6. Now that we have the correct second half of the `=`, let's add the first part back in

```
>>> for line in open('sourcefile.txt'):
...     print line.split('=')[0] + '=' + line.split('=')[-1].replace('TEXT','**MYTEXT**')
... 
static.TEXT.here=change.**MYTEXT**.here

more.static.TEXT.here=change.**MYTEXT**.here.more

even.more.static.TEXT.here=change.**MYTEXT**.here.even.more
```

### 7. Finally, we write it to a new file

```
newfile=open('destinationfile.txt','w')
for line in open('sourcefile.txt'):
txt = line.split('=')[0] + '=' + line.split('=')[-1].replace('TEXT','**MYTEXT**')
    print txt
    newfile.write(txt)
```

### 8. Confirm it looks correct

```
$ cat destinationfile.txt 
static.TEXT.here=change.**MYTEXT**.here
more.static.TEXT.here=change.**MYTEXT**.here.more
even.more.static.TEXT.here=change.**MYTEXT**.here.even.more
```

Could the above be simplified and written better? Of course. Could the above be accomplished with less steps using regex? Yes. But I've included the above steps to hopefully walk you step by step through the procedure to see what's going on with python. Hope it helps.

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply, I have tried implementing the example provided and I don't receive any errors but likewise it does not appear to make changes to the files.

exact code used for reference:

    
    formatted_contents = ''
    for line in open(r"C:\Temp\test\test.txt"):
    line_formatted = line.split('=')[-1].replace( 'TEXT' ,  'MyText' )
    formatted_contents += line_formatted

    
I am fairly new to Python so I'm sure it is something I'm just overlooking

Comment: thank you greatly. I was using regex for the case insensitive flag, but this gave me a much better understanding of the process in python and as it happens there was only two variations (capitalised and not) so I could just add another .replace